# Is there a Spanish version of "dot your i's and cross your t's" that includes the letter 'ñ'?

Tags: expresiones, letras

I'm curious, because putting the tilde over the n seems like it would be the same as dotting an i or crossing a t.  Is there a version of the saying dot your i's and cross your t's" that includes the letter ñ in spanish?

Thanks!

---

Tengo curiosidad, porque colocar la tilde sobre la n parece que sería lo mismo que puntear una i o cruzar una t. ¿Hay alguna versión del dicho "dot your i's" y cruzar "t" que incluya la letra ñ en español?

¡Gracias!

Comment: Yo nunca he escuchado a una persona utilizar la frase "poner los puntos en las i's y cruzas las t's" en una conversación ordinaria, mucho menos pienso que alguien pudiera incluir la ñ en dicha frase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There is not.

We only say **"poner los puntos sobre las íes"**.

We don't add anything about the t or the ñ or any other letter.

I guess it would be too weird to say "poner la virgulilla sobre la ene" so we don't say that when only dotting the i's is enough.

By the way the most used name of the symbol above the n to form the ñ is **[virgulilla](https://dle.rae.es/?id=btCZ7EZ)** in Spanish. [Tilde](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ZkHNOE8) could be any symbol above the letters including the *virgulilla*, but *virgulilla* is more used for the ñ.

Comment: Ah; I learned it as two independent letters ene and eñe.

Comment: @Joshua and that is correct. They are two different letters of the _abecedario_ as seen [here](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=ZvGbeqYw9D6ECGlgby)